# Open apk file after download via DownloadManager

Tags: android, apk

I have downloadManager with BrocastReceiver for knowing when download completed,
the file is new version of current running application
and both have same package name
after i run below code i get a popup screen that show some application to run downloaded apk and i can't install apk

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(uriString));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "kara.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setDataAndType(apkUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent2);
```

thank in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 2 intent.setDataAndType,Problem solved.